# Is there no-loop implementation of sparse dot-products of vectors in Python?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, dot-product

Suppose `X` is a Numpy array of size `(N, d)`. I want to calculate an `N`-by-``N` matrix

```
A[i,j] = S[i,j] * numpy.dot(X[i,:], X[j,:]),
```

where `S` is a sparse array with a few nonzero entries. Of course I can loop over all nonzero entries in `S` to calculate the corresponding `A[i,j]`, but that is slow in Python (even in Numba).

Is there a more elegant (efficient) way to calculate without loops (e.g., by some built-in functions)?

Comment: I don't see a loop in the example code that you show. If you mean "without **iteration**", then no: the calculation fundamentally requires doing repeated calculations with each element of the arrays. Numpy doesn't "know" that S is sparse; you need some kind of data structure specific to sparse arrays. "Of course I can loop over all nonzero entries in S to calculate the corresponding A[i,j], but that is slow in Python (even in Numba)." - every nonzero entry in S is relevant to the result, yes? Then how can you calculate it *without* considering all those entries?

Comment: If you have a *specific* value of X and S with a *specific performance requirement* and a timing result that doesn't meet that requirement, that could be the start of uncovering a proper question. Optimization is *hard*, and most of the work is in figuring out the actual question.

Comment: If you meant, for example, "I want to loop over the nonzero entries, but it's slow *because I don't know which ones are nonzero, and I have to check that on the fly* - well, that's the real issue, isn't it? Again, that sounds like the problem is with [looking for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) a better *representation of* sparse arrays.

Comment: What you are really talking about are loops in python level code; loops abound in compiled code (builtin functions).  There is a `scipy.sparse` module that can encode your sparse matrix.  Its implementation for matrix multiplication is good, but even then sparsity, % of nonzero values, needs to less than about 5% to get any benefit.  But, here you are doing element-wise multiplication with `S`.  So you may just have to compare a regular numpy operation that ignores the sparsity of `S` versus the iteration of the non-zero `ij` pairs.